# What is result when the ResumeBookmark gets a timeout?

Tags: workflow-foundation-4, workflow-foundation

I'm trying to check the result in the MSDM when the resuming bookmark gets a timeout, and I couldn't find a clear answer.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee149798.aspx

```
BookmarkResumptionResult rtv = workflowApplication.ResumeBookmark(bookmarkName, value, bookmarkResumptionTimeout);
```

Should it be NotFound or NotReady?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was unable to find documentation but looking into reflector `System.TimeoutException` will be thrown.